# How do I position a separate type of text into the same line of another text I made?

Tags: html, css

> How do I position a separate type of text I wrote ("Learning made fun. We will make Elementary Math fun and easy to learn!") into the same line with this text: All homework practice and exams in one place. We will help your child succeed?
>
> index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <h1>
                PRODIGIES
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>
        
        <div class = "topic-text">

            <h3>
                Learn Elementary Math.
            </h3>

            <h3>
                Fun and Easy!
            </h3>
            
        </div>

        <div class = "page-text">
            <p>
                Learn and master Math from Grade 1 to Grade 5.
            </p>

            <p>
                We will show you all the tips and tricks to solve Math Problems faster!
            </p>
    
        </div>

    </div>

        <div id='container'>
            <a href = "documentation.html">
                <button class = "button" href = "documentation.html">I AM A PARENT</button>
            </a>

            <a href = "signup.html">
                <button class = "button">I AM A STUDENT</button>
            </a>
    </div>

    <div class = "why-join">
        <h3>
            Why join Prodigies?
        </h3>
        <p id = "why-join-text">
            All homework practice and exams in one place. We will help your child succeed.
            <img id = "HW-Logo" src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/VS%20Programming/Axel%20Math%20Website/HW%20Logo%20Math%20WS.png" alt = "HW Logo" width = "50" height = "50"/>
        </p>
        <p id = "why-join-text-2">
            Learning made fun. We will make Elementary Math fun and easy to learn!
        </p>
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

> documentation.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <header class = "header_doc">
            <h1>
                DOCUMENTATION
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>
    </body>

</html>
```

> teachings.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "rest.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            <h1>
                WHAT WILL I TEACH?
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```

> signup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            <h1>
                SIGN UP
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```

> style.css

```
body {
    background-color: rgb(48, 176, 235); /*The background color of the page*/
    color: rgb(199, 195, 195); /*The color of the words*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; /*The font family of the website*/
}

header{
    font-size: 30px; /*The font size of the header*/
    text-align: center; /* The alignment of the title, Prodigies*/
}

h1 {
    background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); /*The background color of the header*/
}

footer {
    text-align: left;
  }
  
footer h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: silver;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(15, 98, 253, 0.2);
}

.topic-text{
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 86px;
    height: 190px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(48, 176, 235); 
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(30, 109, 255);
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(238, 237, 237);
    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.7s; 
  }

.page-text{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
}

#container{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.button{
    background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); /* Green */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 22px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', Helvetica;
}

.button:hover{
    transition: 0.7s;
    transition-duration: 0.96s;
    background-color: #d6caca;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.why-join{
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 38px;
}

#why-join-text{
    max-width: 220px;
    margin: 2 auto 1rem;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-left: 7.5em;
    padding-top: 1em;
}

#HW-Logo{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 4.2em;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
}

#why-join-text-2{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 220px;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 30em;
    padding-bottom: 32em;
}
```

> To re-explain my situation is that every time I want add this text: Learning made fun. We will make Elementary Math fun and easy to learn! on the same line with this text: All homework practice and exams in one place. We will help your child succeed. It doesn't let me. Please Help!

Comment: Please reduce your code to a *bare minimum*. The standard is a [mcve]

Comment: we will gladly help you, just make your big code reproducible.

Comment: what do u mean by "reproducible"?

Comment: https://ibb.co/0j2q0DT - do you want this in one line?

Comment: No, add the bottom there are 2 small paragraphs that have a maximum width. I want them both in one line but I don't know how to

Comment: https://ibb.co/Hq8jCTF - this it?

Comment: I apologize for my incorrect understanding of english

Comment: YES!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I want those small paragraphs in the same line.

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/7CGLJcZ

Comment: Yes that is it. Can you show me the code?

Comment: yes, of course, I will send you a solution now, and I will explain everything there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I marked all my changes with comments in the css. Also, I wrapped these two paragraphs in an additional div container `.why-join-section` for optimal positioning (this will be correct).

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(48, 176, 235); /*The background color of the page*/
    color: rgb(199, 195, 195); /*The color of the words*/
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif; /*The font family of the website*/
}

header{
    font-size: 30px; /*The font size of the header*/
    text-align: center; /* The alignment of the title, Prodigies*/
}

h1 {
    background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); /*The background color of the header*/
}

footer {
    text-align: left;
  }
  
footer h3 {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 30px;
} 

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  float: right;
  line-height: 90px;
  position: relative;
}

ul li a:hover {
    color: silver;
}

ul li ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 1px;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
}

ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}

ul li ul li {
    width: 180px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(15, 98, 253, 0.2);
}

.topic-text{
    font-size: 38px;
    line-height: 86px;
    height: 190px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(48, 176, 235); 
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(30, 109, 255);
}

ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(238, 237, 237);
    padding: 0 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.7s; 
  }

.page-text{
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 25px;
}

#container{
    text-decoration: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:center;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

.button{
    background-color: rgb(30, 109, 255); /* Green */
    border: none;
    border-radius: 15px 50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 22px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', Helvetica;
}

.button:hover{
    transition: 0.7s;
    transition-duration: 0.96s;
    background-color: #d6caca;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.why-join{
    display: flex; /*add*/
    flex-direction: column; /*add*/
    align-items: center; /*add*/
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 50px;
    font-size: 38px;
}

#why-join-text{
    max-width: 220px;
    margin: 2 auto 1rem;
    font-size: 20px;
   /* padding-left: 7.5em;
    padding-top: 1em;*/  /*delete this it*/
}

  .why-join-section {    
    display: flex; /*add*/
    justify-content: space-between; /*add*/
    width: 700px; /*add*/
    margin: 50px 0 50px 0; /*add*/
  }

#HW-Logo{
    float: left;
    padding-left: 4.2em;
    padding-top: 0.9em;
}

#why-join-text-2{
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 220px;
    font-size: 20px;
   /* margin-left: 30em;
    padding-bottom: 32em;*/ /* delete this it*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>

                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <header>
            <h1>
                PRODIGIES
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>
        
        <div class = "topic-text">

            <h3>
                Learn Elementary Math.
            </h3>

            <h3>
                Fun and Easy!
            </h3>
            
        </div>

        <div class = "page-text">
            <p>
                Learn and master Math from Grade 1 to Grade 5.
            </p>

            <p>
                We will show you all the tips and tricks to solve Math Problems faster!
            </p>
    
        </div>

    </div>

        <div id='container'>
            <a href = "documentation.html">
                <button class = "button" href = "documentation.html">I AM A PARENT</button>
            </a>

            <a href = "signup.html">
                <button class = "button">I AM A STUDENT</button>
            </a>
    </div>

    <div class = "why-join">
        <h3>
            Why join Prodigies?
        </h3>
        <div class="why-join-section">
        <p id = "why-join-text">
            All homework practice and exams in one place. We will help your child succeed.
            <img id = "HW-Logo" src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/VS%20Programming/Axel%20Math%20Website/HW%20Logo%20Math%20WS.png" alt = "HW Logo" width = "50" height = "50"/>
        </p>
        <p id = "why-join-text-2">
            Learning made fun. We will make Elementary Math fun and easy to learn!
        </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    </body>

</html>
documentation.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <header class = "header_doc">
            <h1>
                DOCUMENTATION
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>
    </body>

</html>
teachings.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "rest.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            <h1>
                WHAT WILL I TEACH?
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
signup.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Learn Elementary Math at Prodigies!</title>
        <link rel = "icon" type = "img/jpg" href = "img/prodigies.jpg"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "reset.css"/>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "style.css"/>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:ital,wght@1,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>

        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href = "signup.html">SIGN UP</a>
                </li> 
                <li>
                    <a href = "teachings.html">TEACHINGS</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "documentation.html">DOCUMENTATION <img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/dropdown%20icon.png" alt = "Dropdown Icon" width = "22" height = "19"/></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >About</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Contact</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href = "" >Credits</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href = "index.html">HOME</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        
        <header>
            <h1>
                SIGN UP
                <a href = "index.html" ><img src = "file:///Users/axelpalomino/Desktop/prodigies-logo.jpg" alt = "Prodigies-Logo" width = "60" height = "60"/></a>
            </h1>
        </header>

    </body>

</html>
```